# How can I stop Telephony Service Indicator from popping up with all my chats?

Tags: indicator, 14.10, google-hangouts

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 on a desktop. I have settings that I have kept for years in my home partition, so I always keep that separate and I don't format that partition during installation.

I have Google Chrome installed, and I make heavy use of their "desktop" apps. I use Hangouts all day, every day, and I noticed some really odd (and annoying) behavior. Every time I get a chat from someone, in addition to getting the chat in Hangouts, I get a popup from "Telephony Service Indicator" with the message I received.

It looks like this (note the Hangouts app, and that person's latest chat in the popup):

[image: Telephony Service Indicator hates me.]

I tried to remove the package `telephony-service`, but apt-get tells me I'll also have to remove a few other important-sounding packages, like `indicator-network`, `ubuntu-system-settings` and `unity8`, among others.

I need a way to turn this popup notification off, and/or disassociate my chats from it somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this popup has something to do with my Google account being linked in Online Accounts. In that settings menu, I turned off Empathy's association with Google, and the Telephony Service Indicator popups stopped. Weird.